# Sequelize query with two JOINs on custom fields

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, sequelize.js, inner-join

Currently I've got a solution with the following raw query, which works well.

Here's a [SqlFiddle playground](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a32cb).

And here's the raw query that works well:

```
const sql = `SELECT u.*, g.name AS "gender"
  FROM users u
  INNER JOIN connections con ON con.user_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN completed_quizzes q ON q.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN genders g ON g.id = u.gender_id
  WHERE
    con.other_user_id='foo'
    AND q.quiz_id=1
    AND con.status='approved'
    AND u.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND con.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND q.deleted_at IS NULL
  LIMIT 10
  OFFSET 0
`;
```

But I'm trying to replace it with Sequelize's object modelling. So far, the most meaningful solution I've come up with this:

```
const sequelize = {
      include: [
        {
          model: ConnectionsModel,
          as: 'connections',
          where: { otherUserId: userId, status: ConnectionStatus.approved },
          required: true,
          duplicating: false
        },
        {
          model: CompletedQuizzesModel,
          as: 'completedQuizzes',
          where: { userId, quizId },
          required: true,
          duplicating: false
        },
        {
          model: GendersModel
        }
      ],
      nest: true,
      // have to specify `raw: false`, otherwise Sequelize returns only the first associated record
      raw: false
    };
```

It generates the following query (I've prettified it, for ease of reading):

```
SELECT u.*, g.name AS gender FROM users AS u 
    INNER JOIN connections AS con ON u.id = con.user_id AND (con.status = 'approved' AND con.other_user_id = 'foo') 
    INNER JOIN completed_quizzes AS q ON u.id = q.user_id AND (q.user_id = 'foo' AND q.quiz_id = '1')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN genders AS g ON u.gender_id = g.id 
WHERE u.deleted_at IS NULL 
LIMIT 20 
OFFSET 0;
```

But it returns nothing... no rows. Whereas, the original solution returns the rows as needed.

I can see the difference between the general `where` (which is applied to the whole query in the raw query) and the same attributes appended to the `on` clause in the `join`s. Not sure if that's the problem, though.

Here's the [SqlFiddle playground](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a32cb) again.

Comment: Can you create these tables on http://sqlfiddle.com and fill them with records that would be shown executing the first SQL query but not be shown by executing the second query?

Comment: @Anatoly, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the post with an SqlFiddle URL. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added an extra condition in the `include` option `CompletedQuizzesModel`. In the original SQL query you don't have a condition on `userId`.

So this `include` should be like this:

```js
{
          model: CompletedQuizzesModel,
          as: 'completedQuizzes',
          where: { quizId }, // removed userId
          required: true,
          duplicating: false
        }
```

The result query works just like the original one:

```sql
SELECT u.*, g.name AS gender FROM users AS u 
    INNER JOIN connections AS con ON u.id = con.user_id AND (con.status = 'approved' AND con.other_user_id = 'foo') 
    INNER JOIN completed_quizzes AS q ON u.id = q.user_id AND (q.quiz_id = '1')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN genders AS g ON u.gender_id = g.id 
WHERE u.deleted_at IS NULL 
LIMIT 20 
OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Oh, damn! So subtle!